# Trying to set property in a LINQ GroupBy Select using a loop

Tags: linq

I have the following code:

```
public class Report
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Sales { get; set; }
}

var result = myItems.GroupBy(x => new { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name }).Select(x => new Report { Id = x.Key.Id, Name = x.Key.Name });

foreach (var item in result)
{
    item.Sales = anotherColletion.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == item.Id).Sales;
}
```

I am unable to set the sales property to any value this way. Even if I try:

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    item.Sales = 50;
}
```

However, if I set the property using the following code it works:

```
var result = myItems.GroupBy(x => new { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name }).Select(x => new Report { Id = x.Key.Id, Name = x.Key.Name, Sales = 50 });
```

Is this by design?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that LINQ queries are lazy ("deferred execution"). You *are* setting the property on each result of the query in the `foreach` loop, but these results will essentially disappear into thin air.
When you enumerate the results of the query *again* after your `foreach` (which you haven't shown us), the query is **re-executed** and the results recreated, effectively undoing your changes. Remember that the query is just a specification for how to produce the results, not the results themselves.

A simple fix is to *materialize* the query into a collection first.

```
var result = myItems.GroupBy(x => new { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name })
                    .Select(x => new Report { Id = x.Key.Id, Name = x.Key.Name })
                    .ToList();
```

Your `foreach` will then end up mutating the elements of an in-memory collection rather than the results of a lazy query, and will therefore be visible downstream.

Personally though, consider setting the property in the query itself:

```
var result = myItems.GroupBy(x => new { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name })
                    .Select(x => new Report
                                 { 
                                   Id = x.Key.Id,
                                   Name = x.Key.Name,
                                   Sales = anotherCollection.First(a => a.Id == x.KeyId)
                                                            .Sales
                                  });
```

Comment: If I were to do myItems.ToList() first and then do the GroupBy() without the ToList(), would that work or would that still cause the query to re-execute?

Comment: @Thomas: That should technically work, because the mutable `Report` objects have already been created and materialized by that stage. Only the grouping will re-execute, not the object creation. I strongly recommend not doing that though.

Comment: The reason I would materialize myItems.ToList() is because I want to do multiple GroupBy (not included in this question) on the collection and use those collections for calculations. My reasoning being to run one database query and then use the in memory collection for the other GroupBy. May I ask why you don't recommend doing that?

Comment: @Thomas: Is there any reason not to materialize the results of the `GroupBy` if you are going to enumerate the results multiple times? You want the query to be responsive to changes in the list?

Comment: My thinking was materializing myItems.ToList() to memory and preform operations on the in memory collection (like multiple GroupBy) as opposed to not materializing and fire multiple SQL queries for each operations. So the only reason is the number of queries that might be generated.

Comment: Hang on, is this LINQ to SQL or LINQ to objects? In any case, if this is about efficiency, I suggest posting another question. I don't completely understand the full scenario and it's difficult to explain here. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thomas,

The var results you are using is just a query, when you iterate over it, in the foreach loop, you are generating a new report object but it is not 'stored' anywhere.

Add the ToArray() or ToList() to the end of the query to fix the issue:

```
var result = myItems.GroupBy(x => new { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name }).Select(x => new Report { Id = x.Key.Id, Name = x.Key.Name }).ToList();
```

Amir.